# Terraform state lock not able to release in GCP backend

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

While running terraform in automation i.e. CI/CD in jenkins, if due to some error my pipeline fails, it results in a lock in my state file.
The process to unlock the state file is :

```
terraform force-unlock id
```

This works for me, only if I include this command in my jenkinsfile. This command does not run in cloud shell and gives the error:

```
Local state cannot be unlocked by another process
```

As in azure we have an option to remove the lock through Portal via break lease,
Do we have any option in GCP?

Details:

Terraform v0.15
provider GCP v3.63.0
Backend: GCP storage bucket

Is deleting the default.tflock file the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just renamed lock file name in storage bucket ,it has worked

Answer (score 0):

I just faced the same problem and well I can't say if that's the good way or not but it worked.

I've cancelled my Gitlab Pipeline during apply so the lock kept in place without being able to unlock it. Removing it did the trick

Comment: Deleting the lock file works